# Using AND as a conditional

Tags: php

I came across a wordpress theme which used the following code:

```
is_file and include 'file.php';
```

I have never seen this before so I was rather confused. It works fine in the particular wordpress theme I'm looking at. But if I just take that line of code and run it on its own it includes the file but also gives me the following notice:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant is_file - assumed 'is_file' in (the file path) on line 3
```

But if I do this:

```
is_file('file.php') and include 'file.php';
```

It works fine.

Question 1: Why does this work and where can I read more about using "and" as a conditional?

Question 2: Is it bad coding practice? Is it slower? Any risks? Etc.

Question 3: Why does it work in the wordpress theme but not on its own? (Yes, I use the same PHP settings).

Comment: What do you mean by "not on its own?"

Comment: Outside the wp theme. In its own file. Just that one line of code.

Comment: Maybe because it can't find file.php?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, `and` means "if the statement is true, do this". So the code in your Wordpress is incorrent:

```
is_file and include 'file.php'
```

Since constants should be uppercase. Even if they mean a constant in this case, it wouldn't make sense.

```
is_file('my_file') and include 'my_file.php'
```

is the right way.

The same way, you can use `or`: "if the statement if false, do this", like

```
$payed or my_redirect_function('pay.php'); //go to payment page
```

Comment: Okay. I find it really strange that it includes the file without an error though.

Comment: It's possible. PHP assumes a constant because is_file itself is nothing. It assumes the constant IS_FILE and maybe that one is set to TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

```
is_file('file.php') and include 'file.php';
```

it works because `is_file('file.php')` return `TRUE`

```
is_file and include 'file.php';
```

it did not work because `is_file` return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The AND directive can be treated like a function

```
function and($a, $b)
{
    if($a) return $b;
    else return $a;
}
```

With the only one **exception**. When you pass an expression as second parameter, **it wont even be executed**, when $a is false. This is build-in language optimization, it is guaranteed to behave this way.
This way you can write a chain of expressions, that will execute only, when every one before is false.
It is very often used feature, not only in PHP, it not considered bad practice.

The same thing is about $a or $b:

```
function or($a, $b)
{
    if($a) return $a;
    else return $b;
}
```

Sadly don't know much about wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

The `and` first checks the left operand and if it is false it doesn't need to check the right operand.

I remember reading about it somewhere. Let me see if I can find the link.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But it's strange that it works without giving it any parameters.

Comment: It doesn't work. That's a symptom of PHP's "continue working at all costs".